# How do I self install APK fixing error parsing APK?

Tags: android, xamarin, apk

I have an Android mobile app on a Zebra device that will stay in house.  All that works well but I have been struggling with the updates.  I have code to check version numbers and can download a new signed APK to the device in a folder (MyFolder).  That works.  I can install the update from that folder if need be but the users will need it to just update without having to learn that process.  I have read and tried many things in this group and others, I'm sure it is something super simple.  I make sure the device has the file, the device allows the application to install, and has access to the device storage.  I get the message error parsing package and I'm just not sure where to go next.  Here is code I have

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
```

MainActivity.cs (ProcessUpdate())

```
    Android.Net.Uri fileUri = Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, context.PackageName+".provider", myDir);

    bool binstall = context.PackageManager.CanRequestPackageInstalls();

    if (!binstall)
    {
      context.StartActivity(new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageUnknownAppSources));
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);

    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraNotUnknownSource, true);
    intent.SetDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTask | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);

    try
    {
        context.StartActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex)
    {
        WritetoLog("ActivityNotFoundException ProcessUpdate - " + ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    WritetoLog("Exception ProcessUpdate - " + ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Make sure the package is signed with the same key. Also I would recommend using the [PackageInstaller API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller) instead of firing your own intents. This API is available from API 21 and up.

Comment: @Cheesebaron thank you, I'm working to get it replaced with PackageInstaller, just trying to work through what that looks like while working other projects.

Comment: Waitting for your good news.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I have the PackageInstaller change in my code and I'm not getting any errors, but, my downloaded apk is not updating the app.  So I'm not sure if there is a specific location I needed to download the updated apk to.  I have a folder the app creates for things such as a log file and to get any apk updates, literally called MyFolder.  The app does the update process and closes/reopens but still the same version.  I have checked the updated version on another device and that is right.  So continuing to trudge through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the intent with PackageInstaller and ensured that the Activity was doing  LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop on the CS page.  It does ask the user if they want to install, upon accepting, it closes the app and does not relaunch, but for now that is an easy workaround to relaunch it.

```
    PackageInstaller packageInstaller = context.PackageManager.PackageInstaller;
    PackageInstaller.SessionParams sessionParams = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstallMode.FullInstall);
    int sessionId = packageInstaller.CreateSession(sessionParams);
    var session = packageInstaller.OpenSession(sessionId);

    AddApkToInstallSession(newFile.ToString(), session);

    // Create an install status receiver.
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, this.Class);
    intent.SetAction(PACKAGE_INSTALLED_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    IntentSender statusReceiver = pendingIntent.IntentSender;

    // Commit the session (this will start the installation workflow).
    session.Commit(statusReceiver);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things

1. Make sure that your `myDir` is exposed to file povider
   The file provider should have filePaths

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.myapp.fileprovider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

You file path should be situated in res/xml/filepaths.xml

```
<paths>
    <files-path path="<myDir path>/" name="apk_dir" />
</paths>
```

2. Its better to use `Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE)` intent.